# JSON parsing trouble

Tags: c#, json, parsing

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Stream stream = client.OpenRead(" some link ");
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject jObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
List<String> list = new List<string>();


//loading list
for (int i = 0; i < ((string)jObject["some_stream"][i]["some_channel"]["some_name"]).Count(); i++)
{

  string result = ((string)jObject["some_streams"][i]["some_channel"]["some_name"]);
  list.Insert(i, result);

}

stream.Close();
```

This code is working, but in json data I have 20+ results should be returned, but I only get 8.

What could be the cause?

Comment: It's hard to help without seeing the data... but you should really consider using a `foreach` loop, or using LINQ to create the list.

Comment: Can you post your response Data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are counting the length of a string. at some point the length of that string is equal to or less than i (the 9th value of the string if you manage to iterate 8 times)

That is this piece of code

```
((string)jObject["some_stream"][i]["some_channel"]["some_name"]).Count()
```

returns the length of a string at location `i` so if you manage to iterate 8 times then the string at jObject["some_stream"][9]["some_channel"]["some_name"] has a length of 9 or less at which time the looping ends

From the usage it looks like `jObject["Some_stream"]` returns an array in that case what you could do is something like this:

```
var arr = (Treal[])jObject["Some_stream"];
var list = (from obj in arr
           select ((string)obj["some_channel"]["some_name"])).ToList();
```

you will need to substitue TReal with the actual type of jObject["Some_stream"]

aside: when ever you are opening a stream it's a good idea to do this within a using statement. In your code the stream would not be closed in the case of an exception
the code would then be

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();  
using(var stream = client.OpenRead(" some link ")) {
    reader = new StreamReader(stream);   
    var jObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(reader.ReadLine());  
    var arr = (Treal[])jObject["Some_stream"];
    var list = (from obj in arr
               select ((string)obj["some_channel"]["some_name"])).ToList();
}
```

Comment: y. it's looks realy, but how i can get amount of my results

Comment: what do you me with amount? do you mean the sum? or the count of entries? or something else?

Comment: many thant's. as i understood i nedd replace TReal type to actually type of data uing in jobject?

Comment: hm.. last variant works.. what doing new code?/ it's can pretend some exceptions in future?? because i'm newbie in programming and see no diference and advantages in this. If you can to explain me) thank's

Comment: @tekhitaFanta for small data volumes there's going to be little difference however it's more precis in what it communicates. The latter says: "I know this object is an array of type TReal" where as the former said "I know that this is a sequence of objects of type TReal" for huge datasets the latter would (probably) be noticably faster because it makes one cast instead of (potentially) one for each element

Comment: but i use Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer in place of TReal. it's actually for this?